# Spring @MatrixVariable as a simple map

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wonder if it is possible to get values from `@MatrixVariable` to simple map.

For example I have URL: `http://localhost:8080/myapp/products/price;low=200;high=400`

I know that I can get this values by method:

```
@RequestMapping("/{price}")
public String filterProducts(@MatrixVariable(pathVar = "price") Map<String, List<String>> priceFilter, Model model);
```

How I can pass URL parameters to variable `Map<String, Integer> priceFilter`? Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Don't know if Map<String, Integer> or Map<String, List<Integer>> is possible - doesn't seem to be - but if you want to access them easily and you have a limited number of price types you could use @MatrixVariable(value="low") Integer low, @MatrixVariable(value="high") Integer high, ... adding required=false where not mandatory.